# Using Trace Depenedents Function in LibreOffice Calc Across Sheets in Same File

Tags: libreoffice

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) and have been unable to find an answer to my question.
When another sheet in the same file is identified using the Trace Dependents function in Calc (blue line with square or diamond head), how do I know which sheet(s) and which cell(s) is(are) being referenced by the Trace Dependents function ?

Comment: It seems to be a looong term issue in LibreOffice. And it's still unresolved. Please check this bug report: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63087